# Get Time Difference between Timestamps PYTHON in the format "Seconds.microseconds" [e.g. 0.123456 sec]

Tags: python, pandas

I have imported data from excel (2 columns - Time and Voltage) into 2 NumPy arrays.
The time column is imported as pandas timestamp data (**<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>**) in the format:

```
yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.microseconds (Example below)
2021-12-29 18:39:29.845000
```

I am trying to display a plot with time on the x-axis and voltage on the y-axis. But when I plot it, the time is displayed as HH:MM:SS.

[image]

I want to display the time from 0 to 10 seconds since this is how long each experiment takes but there is no information on how to take an array with timestamp data and convert it to an array of decimal numbers going from 0.000 to 10.000 seconds, for example:

```
time = [0.000, 0.001, 0.002, ... , 9.998, 9.999, 10.000]
```

I have tried things like looping through the array and taking the difference from the first value but that takes 1hour since my data set is 500,000 points long. So even if that did work, I do not have the time to do it for all of the graphs I want to plot.

I have also tried getting the array with the time values and taking away the first value to get the time difference:

```
dateTimeDifference = time - time[0]
```

But i get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'Timestamp'
```

However, I have a feeling that even if i were to do this, i would get an array in the format of 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.microseconds' instead of what i want which is an array in the format 'SS.microseconds'.

Can you help?

Comment: to clarify - what you want is to plot one graph per 10 timestamp points starting from index 0?

Comment: No sorry. I have many datasets. Each dataset has 500000 voltage readings taken in the space of 10 seconds. I want to plot each voltage-time graph for each dataset. I hope that is clearer now!

Comment: The picture I have put into the question shows an example of one dataset. There are in fact 500,000 data points being shown in this plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the pandas timestamps into time difference data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#create sample data
np.random.seed(123)
date_range = pd.date_range("2022-1-3 12:34:50", periods=50, freq="7 ms")
vals = np.random.randint(-10, 50, len(date_range))
df_exp = pd.DataFrame({"Exp_Time": date_range, "Exp_Values": vals})


#convert to seconds
#it is not necessary to store these values in an extra column
#you can also generate them on the fly in the plot 
df_exp["Exp_MS"] = df_exp["Exp_Time"].diff().dt.microseconds.fillna(value=0).cumsum()/1000000

#plot 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(df_exp["Exp_MS"], df_exp["Exp_Values"])
plt.xlabel("Time (in s)")
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

Some additional explanation - the conversion happens here:

`df_exp["Exp_Time"].diff().dt.microseconds.fillna(value=0).cumsum()/1000000`

This is just a series of chained operations:

- take the timestamp column `df_exp["Exp_Time"]`
- calculate the difference between values [`.diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html)
- convert it to datetime microseconds [`.dt.microseconds`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.microseconds.html)
- set the first value to zero [`.fillna(value=0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html)
- create the cumulative sum of the time differences [`.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)
- and finally transform the microsecond values into seconds `/1000000`

Et voila, now you are ready to adapt this to your needs. As mentioned already, you could also simply plot the pandas series directly if you don't use these values again for something else:
`plt.plot(df_exp["Exp_Time"].diff().dt.microseconds.fillna(value=0).cumsum()/1000000, df_exp["Exp_Values"])`

Comment: Cheers for this. I don't quite understand all the extra bits on the end of the "#convert to seconds" code, but I ran the code and it works a treat! Thanks so much.

Comment: The conversion is just a one-liner, the rest is just sample data generation and to show that the plot works as expected. I will add some more explanations - it is not difficult, once you understood the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Try and time this code, where time is your time array. Assign it to new array and use that as your X-axis.

`[i - time[0] for i in time]`